React BrowserRouter alphanumeric ID (for image name, i.e., "JOE.jpg" to component to show image fails
I'm trying to have a route that includes an image, i.e., localhost:30000/image.jpg that goes to a component , but I keep getting an error I don't understand. Can you help resolve this? I'm confused. Thanks!
In #App.js#:
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const { id } = useParams(); 

return(
<div className="App">
    <Route path="/showimages" element={<ShowImage:id />} />
</div>
)

#Page pages/showimage.jsx#:
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import ShowTheImage from "../components/showTheImage/showTheImage";

const ShowImage = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();

    return (
        <div>
        <ShowTheImage id={id} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default ShowImage;


#Component components/showTheImage/showTheImage.jsx
import React from "react";

const showTheImage = (props) => {
    const { id } = props;
    return (
        <div>
            <div>ShowImage</div>
            <img src={`images/${id}.jpg`} alt={`Image ${id}`} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default showTheImage;

ERROR:


I have researched how to add items to the end of the route, and what I've found says that it doesn't have to be numeric. However, I am unable to get the image to show, just this error.

